# Передача параметров из C# в PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Никак не подберу правильную последовательность передачи параметров. Вылетает ошибка, что входная строка имела неверный формат.

Код С#

```
protected void ODS_TechObjs_Inserting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
    {
        object ctrl = gvTechObjs.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl((GridViewDataColumn)gvTechObjs.Columns["namehead"], "idpos");
        object val = ctrl.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, ctrl, null);

        NpgsqlParameter[] pgsqlParams = { new NpgsqlParameter("p_tobject_id", NpgsqlDbType.Integer),
                                          new NpgsqlParameter("p_tobject_name", e.InputParameters["tobject_name"]),
                                          new NpgsqlParameter("p_position_id", NpgsqlDbType.Integer),
                                          new NpgsqlParameter("p_tobject_type",  NpgsqlDbType.Integer),
                                          new NpgsqlParameter("p_tobject_address", e.InputParameters["tobject_address"]) };
        pgsqlParams[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
        pgsqlParams[0].Value = e.InputParameters["tobject_id"];
        pgsqlParams[2].Value = val;
        pgsqlParams[3].Value = e.InputParameters["tobject_type"];
        e.InputParameters.Clear();
        e.InputParameters["pgsqlParams"] = pgsqlParams;
        e.InputParameters["pgsqlProc"] = Resources.PgSQLResources.AddTObjects;
    }
```

Параметры процедуры SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION metrolog.position_addtobjects(
    p_user_name character varying,
    INOUT p_tobject_id integer,
    p_tobject_name character varying,
    p_position_id integer,
    p_tobject_type integer,
    p_tobject_address character varying)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 0
AS $BODY$
```

Comment: ЕМНИП, когда Вы создаете экземпляр NpgsqlParameter, надо к именам параметров добавлять символ ':'.

Comment: В каком месте ?

Comment: В самом начале, то есть имя параметра должно начинаться с ':', например, ":p_tobject_id"

Answer (score 1):

Я сомневаюсь что вы вообще тестировали функцию, и уже пытаетесь вызывать ее откуда-то. Проверить функцию можно прямо в SQL-консоли pgAdmin:

```
 select metrolog.position_addtobject(<какие-нибудь параметры>);
```

Если всё ok - таким же образом и вызывайте функцию из программы C# или любой другой, через выполнение SQL-команды (выше) - запрос вернет строку с результатом, всё как обычно.

Comment: Тестировал, она работает. вся проблема в цифрах массива. pgsqlParams[] . Там нужна точная последовательность - не вижу, где ошибся.

Comment: сформируйте массив по синтаксису PostgreSQL - select metrolog.position_addtobject('{1,2,3,...}') - вот пример http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com.by/2015/09/passing-array-to-plpgsql-function.html
Если прикладная ошибка в коде - выведите строку запроса в консоль отладки и выполните в pgAdmin - будет проще найти где ошибка

Comment: Ваще-то вам там никакие массивы в параметрах не нужны - у вас int нада передать - вызывайте из C# select metrolog.position_addtobject(<id>) и не лазьте по массивам там где это совсем ни к чему.